# Manipulate inscribed parellelepiped in an ellipsoid

Tags: graphics3d, manipulate

Let's say we have an ellipsoid of cartesian equation :
\begin{equation}\frac{x^2}{a}+\frac{y^2}{b}+\frac{z^2}{b}=1 \end{equation}
I want to visualise all the inscribed rectangular parellelepipeds inside this ellipsoid and how the volume changes with the position of the points, so I will need 8 points to manipulate.
Ideally, I'd like to be able to drag the points in the figure while the points stay on the ellipsoid, and in a way such that if I drag a point, the parallelepiped stays rectangular, so the other points in the same planes change simultaneously with that original point, and to have an output that gives the volume of the parallelepiped.
I know I'm asking a lot, so it'd be great to only get some tips about how to proceed (the functions that would be helpful, a simpler example...).

Comment: Do you have any code so far? Like a 3D plot of an ellipsoid or parallelepiped?

Comment: @Domen I just plotted an ellipsoid, I have no idea how to plot the parallelepiped within the same graph.            
                                
    a = b = 1
    c = 1.5
    ContourPlot3D [
    x^2/a + y^2/b + z^2/c == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]

Comment: You can not vary 8 points independently. Every point needs to be on the ellipsoide what gives 1 constriction.  Further, what should "parallelepiped stays rectangular" mean? A parallelepiped need not be rectangular.  Or do you mean a cuboid?

Comment: @DanielHuber A parallelepiped stays rectangular, meaning the planes containing each face stay perpendicular to each other.